# Create a Leaflet custom checkbox control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to create a custom checkbox control which will simply set a flag in jquery/javascript: if checked the flag = 'clustered' or if unchecked flag = 'unclustered'. 
So far I have a control on the map but its not a checkbox and how do i get the state of the checkbox - if its checked/unchecked.

code:

```
function MapShowCommand() {
  alert("checked / unchecked"); //set flag
}

L.Control.Command = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topleft',
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        var controlDiv = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-command');
        L.DomEvent
            .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
            .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault)
        .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', function () { MapShowCommand(); });

        var controlUI = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-command-interior', controlDiv);
        controlUI.title = 'Map Commands';
        return controlDiv;
            }
    });
var test = new L.Control.Command();
map.addControl(test);
```

Comment: Are you using Leaflet Marker Cluster? Is there a reason why you want the check box to be a Leaflet Control and not an HTML element?